# Description on JMX fields and methods JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, mbeans

How can we add description on the fields and operations exposed for JMX?

JBoss version : *JBoss EAP 5.1.2*

We have a Service bean as

```
@Service
@Management(MyConfigMgnt.class)
public class MyConfigService implements MyConfigLocal, MyConfigMgnt {
     public void setMyValue(String MyValue){}
     public String getMyValue(){}
}
```

These methods are declared in the `MyConfigMgnt` interface.

This is visible in the jboss jmx console as [image]

and for the field it is shown as[image]

How do we add relevant and proper information on the fields and the MBean.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of JBoss ?

Comment: JBoss EAP 5.1.2, updated now in question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 ways of doing this.

1. Re-implement your service as a [DynamicMBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) which is slightly more complicated but allows for the definition of attribute and operation meta-data. (i.e. `MyConfigMgnt extends DynamicMBean`)
2. An easier way (but possibly not future-proof) is to use an [XMBean](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Writing_JBoss_MBean_Services-XMBean_Examples.html) descriptor. XMBeans are a proprietary JBoss JMX extension where meta-data is defined in an external XML resource. It would require no actual changes to the source code except the addition of the XMBean resource location which looks something like this:

   @Service(objectName = XMBeanService.OBJECT_NAME, xmbean = "resource:META-INF/service-xmbean.xml")

If you have a very large number of attributes and operations, the XMBean XML descriptor can be arduous to write, but [twiddle](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/12/22/jboss-command-line-utility-twiddle/) has a helper command which will generate a template specific to your existing simple MBean, so you can save the output, fill in the details and go from there.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I used the XMBean descriptor and that helps showing the description.
Thanks